Ensure one value is less than another with JSON schema
Imagine I have a following json schema:
"period": {
           "type": "object",
           "properties": {
           "start": {
              "description": "Unixtime",
              "type": "number",
              "minimum": 0
            },
           "end": {
              "description": "Unixtime",
              "type": "number",
              "minimum": 0
            }
          },
          "required": [
           "start",
           "end"
          ]
        }

Is there a way to ensure that start time is always <= end time with help of schema itself?

It is a schema validation tools. As such its value checks are limited. It does not do logical comparisons. You are expected to do them in code.

JSON Schema on its own doesn't support this, but if you're in .net, my data extension vocabulary can do it.
See my docs for an example: https://docs.json-everything.net/schema/examples/data-ref/#example-schemadata-comparative
To support dates, you'll also need to define keywords that understand string-encoded dates, like minDate and maxDate.
These two combined will get you where you need to be.
